# How would I approach finding the locus of these complex variable equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My textbook gives very little information on how to describe the locus of points for the following: $|z + 2i| + |z - 2i| = 6$ and $z(z^* + 2) = 3$.

I was hoping someone could walk through it and really clear it up for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(1),$

if we take $z=x+iy,$ we get $$\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-2)^2}+\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y+2)^2}=6$$

$$\implies \sqrt{x^2+(y+2)^2}=6-\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}$$

Squaring we get,  $$x^2+(y+2)^2=36+x^2+(y-2)^2-12\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}$$

$$9-2y=3\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}$$

Again, square & rearrange in the form $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-\beta)^2}{b^2}=1$$

Find the third definition of ellipse [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/WhatIsEllipse.shtml)

For $(2),$

if we take $z=x+iy,$ we get $$(x+iy)\{(x-iy)+2\}=3\implies x^2+y^2+2x+i2y=3$$

Compare the real & the imaginary parts

Comment: For (1), is it supposed to equal 3 or 6?

Comment: @David, sorry for the typo. Rectified

Comment: For (1), I got x^2/5 + y^2/9 = 1. I think I understand that better now. For (2), when you say compare the real and imaginary parts, do you mean we get (x^2 + y^2 + 2x) + 2yi = 3? Where 2y is the imaginary part, and x^2 + y^2 + 2x is the real part. That wouldn't be sufficient enough, correct? I'd have to go further.

Comment: Furthermore, the assumption here is that x and y are real, which they definitely are, so this all follows.

Comment: To go one step further, it would be 1/3 (a+1)^2+1/3 (b+i)^2 = 1

Comment: @David, comparing the real and imaginary parts, $y=0$ and $x^2+2x=3\implies (x+3)(x-1)=0\implies x=1,-3$ so the locus is basically two points $(1,0),(-3,0)$

Answer (score 2):

Here is more geometric approach:

We know that $|z-a|$ is the distance between the points $z$ and $a$. Hence the first equation describes the set of those points the sum of whose distance to $2i$ and $-2i$ is constant (which is strictly larger than $|2i-(-2i)|=4$, otherwise the set would be an interval or empty). This is an ellipse with foci $2i$ and $-2i$.

The second one can be written as $|z|^2+2z=3$. So $z$ is real and we have $z^2+2z-3=0$. This equation has two roots and the set consisting of these two points is the answer.